# how to block websites to copy php result in my server?

Tags: php, ajax

this is my code example:

```
$('#list').load('/file.php?id=25');
```

how to block another websites to access and get result from file.php ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), JavaScript code served in the context of another domain can not access your content.

However, a server-side script can always download the website. What you can do against that is:

- Not serve the website in the first place. I'm assuming that's not an option
- Require passwords from trusted users. Note that those users can also store their passwords at a remote server.
- Require [CAPTCHAs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) for each visit. This is bound to annoy your legitimate visitors.
- Require signed hard-/software. Since there is no easy way to do that right now, you'll need every visitor to install custom and/or signed hard- and software. This is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

By deleting `file.php` or by protecting it with a password. There is no other reliable way. If you have a resource publicly accessible on the web, there is always the risk of it being scraped.

The example you show, however, will not work for other sites anyway, because normal Ajax requests can't be cross-domain.

Comment: `The example you show, however, will not work for other sites anyway, because normal Ajax requests can't be cross-domain.` But nothing prevents something / someone to just go to the URL without using AJAX.

Comment: i want to disable other websites get content from http://www.mysite.com/file.php?id=25

Comment: @motioz as said, that is not possible in a reliable way unless you use password protection.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a login system in place, start a session in `file.php` and check if the user is logged in - the session cookie will be sent when the Ajax call is made.